# Drag autofill in excel every x number of rows

Tags: excel

I am vertically populating every 6 rows with 6 cells in another sheet, and then need to jump down a row in the reference for example:

```
B12  
C12  
D12  
E12  
F12  
G12  
B13  
C13  
D13  
E13  
F13  
G13  
B14
```

Because I have thousands of rows that need to follow this pattern, I need to drag and have the drag follow the pattern above. Instead it jumps up by six each repetition.

```
B12
C12
D12
E12
F12
G12
B18
C18
D18
E18
F18
G18
```

Comment: What are the Ellipsis in your expected results intended to represent? Where is your original effort? What have you tried?

Comment: Mine comes out perfect if i select the first 6 and drag down, it increments every 6

Comment: It increments every 6, but by 6. I need it to increment every 6 by 1.

Answer (score 0):

To test, I entered B12 in cell B12, C12 in cell C12 etc down to G14 in cell G14

Put this in A1 and drag down:

```
=OFFSET(A1,(12+TRUNC((ROW(A1)-1)/6))-ROW(A1),MOD(ROW(A1)-1,6)+1)
```

It uses some basic maths to calculate and offset from cell A1

This calculates the row offset:

```
(12+TRUNC((ROW(A1)-1)/6))-ROW(A1)
```

And this calculates the column offset:

```
MOD(ROW(A1)-1,6)+1
```

You can enter these as individual formulas to see how they work.

These are the results for the formula in my test sheet:

```
B12
C12
D12
E12
F12
G12
B13
C13
D13
E13
F13
G13
B14
C14
D14
E14
F14
G14
```